# How do session_id() and $_SESSION relate? (PHP)

Tags: php, session, cookies

What's the difference between the two?

From my understanding of how general authentication works, an ID is stored server-side and client-side. With each request, the client-side sends the cookie over, matches the ID in the server, and outputs the desired data. Thus, when I do:

```
session_start();
session_id();
```

A cookie is also stored client-side. This makes sense to me because in my mind `session_id()` is just generating that ID. We can then store this ID into (for instance) a User table for the given user. Then, with each browser request, we just match up the ID from the cookie and the one in the database.

However, why can't we just stick with the ID for authentication? I've seen online code doing the following, and I don't quite get what the point of setting a field in `$_SESSION` is:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = 'Billy Bobby';
```

Comment: RTFM: "session_id() is used to get or set the session id for the current session."

Comment: Where else are you going to get 'Billy Bobby' from, unless you ask the user to input it?

Comment: Why can't you store the name in the database along with the ID? (kind of like the session_token in Rails)

Answer (score 1):

The Session ID is stored in the cookie client-side.  Server-side, the data (from $_SESSION) is saved in a file (typically) under that Server ID Key.

You can save all the data in a database, but by default there is no persistence between one page view and the second.

The Session ID really has nothing to do with authentication. Though you can use session data to manage an authentication state across multiple requests.

Comment: In Rails, which I'm more familiar with, I kept track of state by having a session_token column for the users table. Then, when a user signs in successfully, a token is generated in the database, and his/her cookie has the token. Thus, with each request, the cookie can be used to find the logged-in user from the database. It seems that in PHP, $_SESSION is used to store the data, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The rails session token is similar to the session id in php, I think.  In PHP, the $_SESSION object is just an abstract interface.  It's actually saving the state information in a file on the disk (by default).  You can also configure PHP to store session data in a database table.

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out, PHP automatically wires up some of the session logic, but it's not entirely secure by default.  IIRC, it uses an int for the token so someone can just run through all possible tokens and hijack someone else's session data.  Or you can hvae collisions if you have mulitple websites on the same server.  It's best to write wrapper getter/setter functions around $_SESSION that saves a random bit of random data in the session, so that it can be confirmed when they access other session data (like username).

Comment: Values stored in the $_SESSION object (like setting `$_SESSION['name'] = 'Bob'`) are stored in that "file" on the disk right? Those values are not stored in the cookie; only the session ID is stored client-side?

Comment: That's correct.  The only thing stored in the client is the ID.  On the disk PHP just serializes the data and saves it under that ID (essentially a big array of data with key value pairs) on the server disk

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks. I initially was confused where the heck the cookie came from (thought it was from setting $_SESSION), and I discovered that `session_start()` actually generates the ID and sends it over to the browser.